# Eclipse vertical toolbar

Tags: eclipse, toolbar

Is it possible to make the toolbar vertical and move it on the left side of the window?[image: eclipse toolbar]

Like this:

[image]

Comment: hmmm! Not sure about that, but as an advanced developer I'm telling you, you won't need it at all when you use Keyboard Shortcuts.

Comment: agree, still if perspective switcher takes the space anyway, why not put some icons under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you implement your own `ApplicationWindow`. Check out [Customizing the workbench](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/rcp_advisor.htm) in Eclipse help.

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse Mars (4.5.1)**

- place the mouse over the small vertical dashed line and wait until it becomes a "move cursor"

  [image: move it over dashed vertical line]
- drag&drop the toolbar on the left side

  [image: vertical toolbar]